# Транслитерация на php

Tags: php, кириллица

Всем привет, у меня есть вопрос по поводу транслитерации в php

У меня есть функция которая работает превосходно

```
function transliterate($st) {
        $st = strtr($st, array(
            'а' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v',
            'г' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e',
            'ё' => 'e', 'ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z',
            'и' => 'i', 'й' => 'y', 'к' => 'k',
            'л' => 'l', 'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n',
            'о' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r',
            'с' => 's', 'т' => 't', 'у' => 'u',
            'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'c',
            'ч' => 'ch', 'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'sch',
            'ь' => '\'', 'ы' => 'y', 'ъ' => '\'',
            'э' => 'e', 'ю' => 'yu', 'я' => 'ya',

            'А' => 'A', 'Б' => 'B', 'В' => 'V',
            'Г' => 'G', 'Д' => 'D', 'Е' => 'E',
            'Ё' => 'E', 'Ж' => 'Zh', 'З' => 'Z',
            'И' => 'I', 'Й' => 'Y', 'К' => 'K',
            'Л' => 'L', 'М' => 'M', 'Н' => 'N',
            'О' => 'O', 'П' => 'P', 'Р' => 'R',
            'С' => 'S', 'Т' => 'T', 'У' => 'U',
            'Ф' => 'F', 'Х' => 'H', 'Ц' => 'C',
            'Ч' => 'Ch', 'Ш' => 'Sh', 'Щ' => 'Sch',
            'Ь' => '\'', 'Ы' => 'Y', 'Ъ' => '\'',
            'Э' => 'E', 'Ю' => 'Yu', 'Я' => 'Ya',
        ));
        return $st;
    }
```

Эта функция берет Кириллический текст и переводит в Латиницу.
Теперь вопрос, как сделать обратное действие при помощи этой функции, просто очень не хочется создавать такую же функцию но в обратном порядке

Comment: а точно возможна обратная транслитерация 1 к 1? как вы будете разбирать транслитерированное слово `shashlyk` к примеру? что получится `схасхлык` или `шашлык` ? чтобы была возможна обратная транслитерация, надо, чтобы все значения были уникальны. Поэтому и надо две функции прямая и обратная. Но и тогда это будет просто транслитерация с русского на латиницу и с латиницы на русский (типа транскрипции), но восстановить обратно русский транслитерированный текст не получится. Если нужна именно обратимость транслитерации, рекомендую статью https://habr.com/ru/post/265455/

Comment: array_flip (пример снизу) + уникальные сочетания для букв

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить дополнительный параметр в функцию и от него плясать

```
function transliterate($st, $rotate = false) {
    $letters = array(
        'а' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v',
        'г' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e',
        'ё' => 'e', 'ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z',
        'и' => 'i', 'й' => 'y', 'к' => 'k',
        'л' => 'l', 'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n',
        'о' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r',
        'с' => 's', 'т' => 't', 'у' => 'u',
        'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'c',
        'ч' => 'ch', 'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'sch',
        'ь' => '\'', 'ы' => 'y', 'ъ' => '\'',
        'э' => 'e', 'ю' => 'yu', 'я' => 'ya',

        'А' => 'A', 'Б' => 'B', 'В' => 'V',
        'Г' => 'G', 'Д' => 'D', 'Е' => 'E',
        'Ё' => 'E', 'Ж' => 'Zh', 'З' => 'Z',
        'И' => 'I', 'Й' => 'Y', 'К' => 'K',
        'Л' => 'L', 'М' => 'M', 'Н' => 'N',
        'О' => 'O', 'П' => 'P', 'Р' => 'R',
        'С' => 'S', 'Т' => 'T', 'У' => 'U',
        'Ф' => 'F', 'Х' => 'H', 'Ц' => 'C',
        'Ч' => 'Ch', 'Ш' => 'Sh', 'Щ' => 'Sch',
        'Ь' => '\'', 'Ы' => 'Y', 'Ъ' => '\'',
        'Э' => 'E', 'Ю' => 'Yu', 'Я' => 'Ya',
    );
    $letters = $rotate ? array_flip($letters) : $letters;
    $st = strtr($st, $letters);
    return $st;
}
```

Comment: `transliterate('расчёска', 0) => rascheska`, а наоборот - `transliterate('rascheska', 1) => ???`